# how can i get an hash/md5 from an object?

Tags: java, hash, md5

I have a class like this

```
Class A{

  private String string1;
  private String string2;
  ..
  ..

  private String string19;

}
```

Some of the strings may be empty.

I want to get an hash/identifier (string or number) for the instances of this class.
I can use hashCode but i don't know if i can get some collision, i have a lot of instances of this class (about 4-5 million).

I need a fast way to get this hash.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will always have collisions.

Comment: As SLaks said, you will get collisions when they have the same data in the same fields.  That's usually desirable when hashing though...

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand this is ok for me, if the same data in the same object so same hash, i want to be sure when they are different

Comment: @res1: You can't be 100% sure if you're using hashes. Different data could hash to the same value. (However, you can always compare the objects after the hashes match to see.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom `hashCode` method that uses a slightly altered version of the `hashCode` algorithm in the String class.  From the Oracle documentation, the String `hashCode` is computed as follows:

```
 s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

You could implement a modified version where you compute `n` over all the String objects in your class.  This way you are not wasting space and time creating a concatenated String to do the same.  In some circumstances this might be fine, but with 4-5 million objects, you probably want to avoid that much churn.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all of the strings, and then do a hash of your choosing on it.  If the string is null, you can use "Null" or any other string -- it really doesn't matter as long as you're consistent.

Comment: but if you have an object1: string1 = "a", string2="b" ( i don't consider other fields for this example), and object2: String1="ab", string2="" then concatenating and calculating hash you get the same result, but the 2 objects are differents.

Comment: Good point.  You could put a separator in there.  It could be a character that won't occur naturally in your variables (like a really high or low Unicode character).